# ReactJs: Should containers to components be a 1:1 relationship?

Tags: reactjs

In reference to [Smart and Dumb Components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.jzodgfm6h), should there be a 1:1 mapping to the smart containers vs. the dumb presentational components or 1:many?

For example, with the simple app I'm building now, the decision point is around either:

**Choice 1**

```
- RootContainer
  - Component A
  - Component B
```

Or

**Choice 2**

```
- RootContainer
  - Container A
      - Component A
  - Container B
      - Component B
```

Which is the preferred way with React?

Comment: There is no preferred way, do what makes sense for your app. Without any extra knowledge about your app choice 1 looks better because there are fewer components and less is more.

Answer (score 1):

There is no one way for every application. If you are using Redux in your application, you should move towards having a container for each component that requires data from the store. This container will manage the data that will be consumed by the child/dumb component, e.g. subscribe to the Redux store, make API calls, then pass this data into the child/dumb component.

Don't worry too much about whether your child/dumb component also contains components and where the data fetching for these should take place. Start with a one-to-one, then you always have the option later on of consolidating where the data fetching occurs.